# Iterating through dictionary items from Django html template

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and like to learn the basics first. I was looking for an answer about iterating dictionary from a template. There are couple of questions similar to mine but no one mention the way that is the simplest and works. However, as I don't have enough reputation I can't comment. Therefor, I created this one here as I really want it to be seen.

Example: let's say we create our dictionary in the def inside views.py as below:

```py
def home_page(request):

    person = {"name": "Saif", "Phone": 111111111}
    context = {"person": person.items}

    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Then in home.html for example, we can iterate easily:

```
    {% block body %}

      {% for key, value in person %}
        <p>{{ key }}:{{ value }}</p>
      {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

I tried other answers but all didn't work and this one works for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In you example you assigning a function (not a result of call function) to a key

```py
>>> person = {"name": "Saif", "Phone": 111111111}
... context = {"person": person.items}

>>> print(context)
{'person': <built-in method items of dict object at 0x109073280>}
```

You can fix this by calling this function:

```
person = {"name": "Saif", "Phone": 111111111}
context = {"person": person.items()}

print(context)
{'person': dict_items([('name', 'Saif'), ('Phone', 111111111)])}
```

(^*make notice we add `()` to method, that means we call it*)

After that your home.html should work as is.

```
{% block body %}

  {% for key, value in person %}
    <p>{{ key }}:{{ value }}</p>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

---

Other solution

For better flexibility and control with you data in html template in future consider to put your `person` dictionary to context as is (without calling `items()`):

```py
>>> person = {"name": "Saif", "Phone": 111111111}
... context = {"person": person}

>>> print(context)
{'person': {'name': 'Saif', 'Phone': 111111111}}
```

And in html template you can now choose how to iterate through dictionary.

By key and value simultaneously:

```
{% for key, value in person.items() %}
    <p>{{ key }}:{{ value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Or just by key:

```
{% for key in person %}
    <p>{{ key }}:{{ person[key] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That’s what I tried before, but I didn’t get anything.

Comment: @SaifAlabachi I updated my answer , pls check it. It should help